# RewriteRule match base path/url

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to have a RewriteRule match the "base" url/path of my site.

My base URL, once in prod, will be something like `http://www.site.com`, but is currently `http://localhost/dev/site/` in dev. `.htaccess` file is in the "site" folder.

In the following examples, **the first RewriteRule is the problem**, and I can't get it to work. The 2nd and 3rd RewriteRules work fine. I need it to bring to index.php?l=default&rte=index if I reach the base path/URL.

Thanks.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/$ index.php?l=default&rte=index [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/$ index.php?l=$1&rte=index [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/([a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?l=$1&rte=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?l=default&rte=index [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/?$ index.php?l=$1&rte=index [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/([a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ index.php?l=$1&rte=$2 [QSA,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to work. I am trying to get `$_GET['l']` and `$_GET['rte']` values when reaching `http://localhost/dev/site/` but those are empty. First rule `RewriteRule ^/$ index.php?l=default&rte=index [QSA,L]` doesn't match `http://localhost/dev/site/`